# Cleaning lego: substances that can be safely used without causing damage?

Tags: cleaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lego cleaning techniques and tools](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/124/lego-cleaning-techniques-and-tools)

I've used a normal washing up solution of Fairy washing up liquid and warm water to good effect previously, but I do find the blocks attract dust very quickly.

Has anyone used anything else?